# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP issue in dynamic web project

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

When i want connect to MySql using JSP, i encounted that error "`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP, An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /index.jsp DbClass cannot be resolved`" whereas everything look like normally in my code. Firstly i tought it would be caused by the MySQL jar file but didn't. Doesn't it have to be the class file (DbClass.class) in my project?

[image]

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="com.sampleWeb.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>sampleWeb</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% 
            Connection c = DbClass.connect();
            out.println(c);
            DbClass.closeConnection(c);
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**DbClass.java**

```
package com.sampleWeb;

import java.sql.*;

public class DbClass {

    public DbClass(){}

    public static Connection connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
        } catch() {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static boolean closeConnection(Connection conn) {
        try{
            conn.close();
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to import the class like this: <%@ page import="com.sampleWeb.DbClass,java.sql.*"%>

Comment: firstly thanks for aid, unfortunatelly, i had tried this before

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Then you can accept it and upvote it, by clicking on the check-mark and arrow-up on the left side. If you still have trouble, please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. I tested it.
The only thing was the empty catch parentheses `} catch() {`.
I can imagine that compilation issues in the DbClass could made it unresolvable.
In order to test this assumtion and to localize the issue, try simplifying the DbClass to simple return:

```
package com.sampleWeb;

public class DbClass {
    public static String connect() {
         return "test";
    }
}
```